# how to show popup notification after ending call in flutter

Tags: flutter

how to add default caller id to flutter to show popup notification of call duration, call cost, main balance after ending calls

I need some suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the flutter local notifications package to display a popup notification after terminating a call in Flutter.**

**Initialize the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin:**

> FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
> FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

**Add the initialization code in your initState() method**:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}
```

**Add the following code after ending the call to display the notification:**

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  'your channel id',
  'your channel name',
  'your channel description',
  importance: Importance.high,
  priority: Priority.high,
  ticker: 'ticker'
);
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  0,
  'Call Ended',
  'Tap to open the app.',
  platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: 'item x',
);
```

For Further Detail Read This package [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)